# Multi-dimensional filtering using scipy.ndimage_generic_filter

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, scipy, filtering

I would like to use a [generic filter](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.filters.generic_filter.html) to calculate the mean of values within a given window (or kernel), for values that fulfill a couple of conditions. I expected the following code to produce a mean filter of the first array in a 3-layer window, using the other two arrays to mask values from the mean calculation.

```
from scipy import ndimage
import numpy as np

#some test data
tstArr = np.random.rand(3,7,7)
tstArr = tstArr*10
tstArr = np.int_(tstArr)
tstArr[1] = tstArr[1]*100
tstArr[2] = tstArr[2] *1000

#mean function
def testFun(tstData,processLayer,nLayers,kernelSize):
    funData= tstData.reshape((nLayers,kernelSize,kernelSize))
    meanLayer = funData[processLayer]
    maskedData = meanLayer[(funData[1]>1)&(funData[2]<9000)]
    returnMean = np.mean(maskedData)
    return returnMean

#number of layers in the array
nLayers = np.shape(tstArr)[0]         

#window size
kernelSize = 5 

#create a sampling window of 5x5 elements from each array             
footprnt = np.ones((nLayers,kernelSize,kernelSize),dtype = np.int)      

# calculate the mean of the first layer in the array (other two are for masking)
processLayer = 0                      

tstOut = ndimage.generic_filter(tstArr, testFun, footprint=footprnt,        extra_arguments = (processLayer,nLayers,kernelSize))
```

I thought this would yield a 7x7 array of masked mean values from the first layer in the input array. The output is a 3x7x7 array, and I don't understand what the values represent. I'm not sure how to produce the "masked" mean-filtered array, or how to interpret the output as given.

Answer (score 0):

Your code produce a mean filter of the first array in a 3-layer window, using the over two arrays to mask values from the mean calculation. You will find the result in `tstOut[1]`.

What is going on ? When you call `ndimage.generic_filter` with `tstArr` of shape `(3, 7, 7)` and `footprint=np.ones((3, 5, 5))` then for all `i` from 0 to 2, for all `j` from 0 to 6 and for all `k` from 0 to 6, `testFun` is called with the subarray of `tstArr` centered in `(i, j, k)` and of shape `(3, 5, 5)` (the array is reflected at the boundary to supply missing values).

In the end:

- `tstOut[0]` is the mean filter of `tstArr[0]` with `tstArr[0]` and `tstArr[1]` as masks
- `tstOut[1]` is the mean filter of `tstArr[0]` with `tstArr[1]` and `tstArr[2]` as masks
- `tstOut[2]` is the mean filter of `tstArr[1]` with `tstArr[2]` and `tstArr[2]` as masks

Again, the wanted result is in `tstOut[1]`.

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Thanks. I'm worried this is an inefficient way to do the job. Is there a way to just return tstOut[1]? Or even better, is there a way to return the mean filter of tstArr[0] with tstArr[1] and tstArr[2] as masks, and tstArr[1] with tstArr[1] and tstArr[2] as masks?